# groupby returning groups on keys not present in data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am participating in a Kaggle Challenge (M5 forecasting accuracy)
Below is a snippet of code where I am confused as pandas.groupby is returning groups on id not present in dataframe.

```
X_train.sort_values('date').head()
```

[image]

```
df_temp = X_train.loc[X_train['id']=='FOODS_3_752_WI_2', :]
df_temp.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.index)
id
FOODS_1_001_CA_1        Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
FOODS_1_001_CA_2        Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
FOODS_1_001_CA_3        Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
FOODS_1_001_CA_4        Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
FOODS_1_001_TX_1        Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
                                    ...              
HOUSEHOLD_2_516_TX_2    Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
HOUSEHOLD_2_516_TX_3    Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
HOUSEHOLD_2_516_WI_1    Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
HOUSEHOLD_2_516_WI_2    Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
HOUSEHOLD_2_516_WI_3    Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Length: 30490, dtype: object
```

But

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['asdf','zxcv'], 'b': [1,2]})
df1
    a   b
0   asdf    1
1   zxcv    2

df2 = df1.loc[df1['a']=='asdf', :]
np.array(df2.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x.index))
```

gives

```
array([Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')], dtype=object)
```

So why is

```
df_temp.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.index)
```

giving all the ids ?

Note: X_train is also a sliced dataframe of another dataframe *df_train_val_test*. 
but even for that

```
df_temp2 = df_train_val_test.loc[df_train_val_test['id']=='FOODS_3_752_WI_2', :]
df_temp2.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.index)
id
FOODS_1_001_CA_1        Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
FOODS_1_001_CA_2        Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
FOODS_1_001_CA_3        Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
FOODS_1_001_CA_4        Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
FOODS_1_001_TX_1        Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
                                    ...              
HOUSEHOLD_2_516_TX_2    Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
HOUSEHOLD_2_516_TX_3    Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
HOUSEHOLD_2_516_WI_1    Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
HOUSEHOLD_2_516_WI_2    Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
HOUSEHOLD_2_516_WI_3    Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Length: 30490, dtype: object
```

Comment: How working if change `df_temp = X_train.loc[X_train['id']=='FOODS_3_752_WI_2', :]` to `df_temp = X_train.loc[X_train['id']=='FOODS_3_752_WI_2', :].copy()` ?

Comment: can you provide a portion of the data? are any of the columns categorical data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When grouping by categorical columns, all categories are returned in the index of the grouped object unless you pass `observed=True`.

From the pandas docs on [GroupBy: Handling of un-observed categorical values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#handling-of-un-observed-categorical-values):

> When using a Categorical grouper (as a single grouper, or as part of multiple groupers), the observed keyword controls whether to return a cartesian product of all possible groupers values (observed=False) or only those that are observed groupers (observed=True).
>
> Show all values:
>
> ```py
> In [164]: pd.Series([1, 1, 1]).groupby(pd.Categorical(['a', 'a', 'a'],
>    .....:                                             categories=['a', 'b']),
>    .....:                              observed=False).count()
>    .....: 
> Out[164]: 
> a    3
> b    0
> dtype: int64
> ```
>
> Show only the observed values:
>
> ```py
> In [165]: pd.Series([1, 1, 1]).groupby(pd.Categorical(['a', 'a', 'a'],
>    .....:                                             categories=['a', 'b']),
>    .....:                              observed=True).count()
>    .....: 
> Out[165]: 
> a    3
> dtype: int64
> ```
>
> The returned dtype of the grouped will always include all of the categories that were grouped.
>
> ```py
> In [166]: s = pd.Series([1, 1, 1]).groupby(pd.Categorical(['a', 'a', 'a'],
>    .....:                                                 categories=['a', 'b']),
>    .....:                                  observed=False).count()
>    .....: 
>
> In [167]: s.index.dtype
> Out[167]: CategoricalDtype(categories=['a', 'b'], ordered=False)
> ```